# how to select row from one of three tables based on fourth table that holds order of those entries from all three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have three tables with content and one that holds row order of those three tables

here are the tables

```
table content_order
id | content_type | content id
1 | content1 | 1
2 | content1 | 2
3 | content3 | 1
4 | content2 | 1

table content1
id | some_text
1 | aaaa
2 | bbb

table content2
id | some_text
1 | text yyyy

table content3
id | some_text
1 | text bbbb
```

so how do I get this?

```
content_type | some_text | content_id
content1 | aaaa | 1 | 
content2 | bbb | 2 | 
content3 | yyyy | 1 | 
content2 | bbbb | 1 |
```

Comment: looks like your results has a typo.  shouldn't the 2nd line be content1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT content_type, some_text, id as content_id
FROM (
               SELECT 'content1' as content_type, content1.Id, content1.some_text
     UNION ALL SELECT 'content2', content2.Id, content2.some_text
     UNION ALL SELECT 'content3', content3.Id, content3.some_text) contents
JOIN content_order
  ON content_order.content_type = contents.content_type
 AND content_order.content_Id = contents.Id
ORDER BY content_order.id
```

Comment: He wants it in order of content_order.id

Answer (score 1):

This would work on t-sql, there might be slight differences for mysql.

```
select co.content_type,
       coalesce(c1.some_text,c2.some_text,c3.some_text) as some_text,
       coalesce(c1.id,c2.id,c3.id) as content_id
from content_order co
left join content1 c1 on co.content_id = c1.id and co.content_type = 'content1'
left join content2 c2 on co.content_id = c2.id and co.content_type = 'content2'
left join content3 c3 on co.content_id = c3.id and co.content_type = 'content3'
order by co.id
```

Comment: this is good one but the answer bellow fits better since I don't have all the same rows in all three tables

Comment: @luka - If you understood sql you would know the number of rows on the 3 content tables does not matter and my solution is significantly faster.